# play2 Java EBean ORM: Inheritance and Generics

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, playframework, ebean

We have the following model classes in Play Framework 2 using Java and EBean ORM:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Data<T> extends Model {

    private T value;

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class DecimalData extends Data<BigDecimal> {
}
```

the latter being an example for a subclass of `Data<T>`. Other subclasses are parametrized with `String` or `BigInteger`.

The generated DDL does not contain any (join)tables or columns for `value`.

Is it in general possible to generate a db scheme for this data model containing generics?
If not, what would be a clean design for Java and the database?

**Edit:** After rethinking the problem, the expected db scheme should look like:

`| decimal_value | string_value | big_integer_value |`

I tried the following workarounds:

1. Instead of a generic type `Object` is used in the superclass and specialized in the subclasses: The generated DDL does not contain any hint of a value column.
2. Leave out `value` in the superclass completly and add it in each subclass: Works, if the `value` attributes have different column name specifications: `@Column(name="decimal_value")`, otherwise only on value with a random type exists.
   This option is so far the best, but still a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Due to type erasure, the type parameters of generics are not available at runtime. Since EBean works through reflection at runtime it can't use the generic type parameters. That's why your original solution doesn't work.

I don't understand your workaround 1, AFAK, you can't change the type of a property in an derived object. You can write methods with different types, but they have different signatures and thus are independent from the original ones.

Your workaround 2 with different column names is the best solution imho.